# Jenkins Git plugin does not expand variables in refspec from Github Integration plugin

Tags: github, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'm trying to use this plugin:

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/GitHub+Integration+Plugin

which should export a variable GITHUB_PR_NUMBER, that corresponds to the branch GitHub is using for pull-requests.

The installation instructions say to add this to the refspec:
`+refs/pull/${GITHUB_PR_NUMBER}/merge:refs/remotes/origin/pull/${GITHUB_PR_NUMBER}/merge`

And this to the branch specifier:
`origin/pull/${GITHUB_PR_NUMBER}/merge`

However this variable does not expand at all.  BUILD_NUMBER seems to expand fine, though.

Not sure what's wrong with my Jenkins setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Immediately after posting, I naturally find the answer in the FAQ: add
`-Dhudson.model.ParametersAction.keepUndefinedParameters=true` to jenkins config.xml on startup.

I guess the variables are undefined initially and get filled in later.

Comment: Not recommended, it is a security issue: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/SECURITY/Jenkins+Security+Advisory+2016-05-11 It would be better to declare all the variables you need as parameters to the job.

Comment: I did see there is a whitelist option later, but working at all takes priority over securing it once it is working. I'm in the middle of a very painful build server redo and sadly, it isn't working yet.